# Detect duplicate elements in subset of given list of numbers

Tags: algorithm

I have a set of numbers say : 1 1 2 8 5 6 6 7 8 8 4 2...

I want to detect the duplicate element in sub-array (of given size say k) of the above numbers... For example : Consider the increasing sub arrays for  k=3`

```
Sub array 1 :{1,1,2}
Sub array 2 :{1,2,8}
Sub array 3 :{2,8,5}
Sub array 4 :{8,5,6}
Sub array 5 :{5,6,6}
Sub array 6 :{6,6,7}
....
```

So my algorithm should detect that sub-arrays 1, 5, and 6 contain duplicates..
My approach :

1)Copy the 1st k elements to a temporary array(vector)

2) using #include file in C++ STL...using unique() I would determine if there's any change in size of vector..

Any other clue how to approach this problem....because my method would consume lot of time and space if the list of the given number is large..

Comment: Space is `O(k)` and time is `O(nk)`, not sure it is a "lot". What time&space complexity are you expecting?

Comment: Also note: "subsets" do not contain duplicates by definition of "set" you probably mean "sub array" or "sub list" (editted)

Comment: @Amit )) Time complexity -> O(n) or O(nlogk) .. and U are right I should not have used the word subset..I didnot know which other word to use..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`O(n)` average time and `O(k)` space solution could be to build a hash-based [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram), and iterate the array while maintaining #occurances for elements in each sublist.

In each iteration, kick the eldest element out (by decreasing the relevant entrance in the histogram) and add a new element.

Also maintain a `numDupes` variable, which counts how many dupes you currently have and is maintained when adding/removing elements from the current candidate.

Pseudo code (sorry if I have off by 1 error or something, but this is the idea):

```
numDupes = 0
histogram = new map<int,int>;
//first set:
for each i form 0 to k:
  if histogram.contains(arr[i]):
     histogram.put(arr[i],histogram.get(arr[i]) + 1)
     numDupes += 1
  else:
     histogram.put(arr[i],1)
//each iteration is for a new set
if (numDupes > 0) print 1 //first sub array has dupes
for each i from k to n:
   if (histogram.get(arr[i-k]) > 1) numDupes -= 1 //we just removed a dupe
   histogram.put(arr[i-k],histogram.get(arr[i-k] - 1)) //take off "eldest" element.
   if (histogram.contains(arr[i]) && histogram.get(arr[i]) > 0):
       histogram.put(arr[i],histogram,get(arr[i]) + 1))
       numDupes += 1 //we just added a dupe
   else:
       histogram.put(arr[i],1)
   if (numDupes > 0) print i-k+1 // the current sub array contains a dupe
```

---

The initial answer had a small mistake: It failקג to catch cases when the last element added did not cause the dupe, but there is still one (like sub array 6 in the example).

It can be solved by maintaining an extra integer that counts the number of current dupes found, and print the sub-array when the counter is greater then 0. (updated the pseudo code).

Also note: To achieve `O(k)` space, your `histogram` needs to delete elements when their value is 0.